# convert `NULL` to string (empty or literally `NULL`)

Tags: r

I receive a list `test` that may contain or miss a certain `name` variable.

When I retrieve items by name, e.g. `temp = test[[name]]` in case `name` is missing I `temp` is `NULL`. In other cases, `temp` has inadequate value, so I want to throw a warning, something like `name value XXX is invalid`, where XXX is `temp` (I use `sprintf` for that purpose) and assign the default value.

However, I have a hard time converting it to string. Is there one-liner in R to do this?

`as.character` produces `character(0)` which turns the whole `sprintf` argument to `character(0)`.

Workflow typically looks like:

```
for (name in name_list){
  temp = test[[name]]
  if(is.null(temp) || is_invalid(temp) {
    warning(sprintf('%s is invalid parameter value for %s', as.character(temp), name))
    result = assign_default(name)
    } else {
    result = temp
    print(sprintf('parameter %s is OK', name)
    }
  }
```

PS. 
`is_invalid` is function defined elsewhere. I need subsitute of `as.character` that would return `''` or `'NULL'`.

Comment: it's not exactly what I meant. I want smth like `ifelse(is.null(temp) || is_invalid(temp), sprintf('%s is not a valid name', as.character(temp))`. Only `as.character` returns `character(0)`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want an `is_invalid` function?

Answer (score 3):

```
test = list(t1 = "a", t2 = NULL, t3 = "b")

foo = function(x){
    ifelse(is.null(test[[x]]), paste(x, "is not valid"), test[[x]])
}

foo("t1")
#[1] "a"

foo("t2")
#[1] "t2 is not valid"

foo("r")
#[1] "r is not valid"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format()` to convert NULL to "NULL".

In your example it would be:

```r
    warning(sprintf('%s is invalid parameter value for %s', format(temp), name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as ultimately my goal was to join two strings, one of which might be empty (null), I realized, I just can use `paste(temp, "name is empty or invalid")` as my warning string. It doesn't exactly convert `NULL` to the string, but it's a solution.

Comment: What about `is_invalid <- function(x, name) !name %in% names(x)`?